# What is right and less error-prone approach that the community follows for the use of IDs in Android's Activity xml

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout ..>
    ...
    ...
    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberOfPersons" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCostPerPerson"
        android:labelFor="@+id/costPerPerson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/costPerPerson"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/costPerPerson"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/costPerPerson"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/costPerPerson"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtCostPerPerson"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space4"
        android:inputType="number" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above xml code snippet has TextView having attribute `labelFor="@+id/costPerPerson"` whose value is the id of the EditText that follows below.

I'm confused on the convention of weather I should use the way it is now, or should the @+id be used in EditText and it is referenced other way here, if so what is it? What is right and less error-prone approach that the community follows? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't matter. personally I would put the plus on the view that is being created i.e. what it belongs to (because the `+` means _give me a new id_). In this case the `EditText`. Sometimes you are forced to not follow this rule because of top down parsing & as I said it doesn't matter.
The real questions is `@id/camelCaseId` or `@id/under_score_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an IDE and its graphical layout editor, you're probably letting it handle these things.

In cases where you are doing this work more by hand, the long-standing guidance has been to put the `+` on the first occurrence of the ID, top-down, in the layout file. In your case, `costPerPerson` appears first in `android:labelFor` of the `txtCostPerPerson` `TextView`, and so your code is following this convention.